# How to create my own feedback page

Tags: android

I want to create a feedback activity page. The feedback page I created had a TextView and a button. I want the users to write their feedback in the TextView and on button click send the written text to my gmail account. How can I do this? Is this even possible?

Comment: Ofcourse it is possible. Try it, and show us where you're stuck.

Comment: "Is this even possible?" This question suggests that you didn't search anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is definitely possible.

```
Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"youremail@yahoo.com"});          
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "message");
email.setType("message/rfc822");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an Email client :"));
```

Now if you want an example related to this, just refer this link : http://www.mkyong.com/android/how-to-send-email-in-android/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Send in this format already answered,

```
  Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
   i.setType("message/rfc822");
   i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"recipient@example.com"});
   i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject of email");
   i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "body of email");
   try {
   startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
   Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "There are no email clients installed.",       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
```